# How to update one time column based on another in jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

Let's assume a super simple use-case:
Imagine, I have a table (dummyTable) with these columns:

```
id
dueAt
createdAt
```

How do I perform a bulk update like the one below using jOOQ

```
update dummyTable
set dueAt = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, 5, createdAt) 
where ids in (...)
```

I see examples online that uses hardcoded and supplied values -
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/datetime-functions/timestampadd-function/. But I couldn't figure out how to get the TIMESTAMPADD function work with existing column values.

What should I have it in the blank?

```
return rwContext
        .update(DUMMYTABLE)
        .set(DUMMYTABLE.DUEAT, ______________ )
        .where(DUMMYTABLE.ID.in(someIds))
        .execute();
```

I tried the below code in the blank but it gives a compilation error

```
timestampAdd(Timestamp.valueOf(DUMMYTABLE.CREATEDAT), 5, DatePart.MINUTE)
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try using the cast method on CREATEDAT with SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Timestamp.valueOf(String)` is JDBC API to create a `Timestamp` value from a string literal, e.g.

```java
Timestamp.valueOf("2000-01-01 00:00:00.0");
```

You cannot pass a jOOQ `Field<Timestamp>` to it. But why would you? Just pass the field reference to the function directly:

```java
timestampAdd(DUMMYTABLE.CREATEDAT, 5, DatePart.MINUTE);
```

Or, if using JSR 310 types, [`DSL.localDateTimeAdd()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#localDateTimeAdd(org.jooq.Field,java.lang.Number,org.jooq.DatePart)):

```java
localDateTimeAdd(DUMMYTABLE.CREATEDAT, 5, DatePart.MINUTE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's actually where I started but that ends in a compilation error

no suitable method found for timestampAdd(org.jooq.TableField<org.jooq.generated.tables.records.DummyTable,java.time.LocalDateTime>,int,org.jooq.DatePart). 

Am I missing something basic?